# Display multiple column data in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need to display two columns of dataset; first column is the `Checkbox` items and second column would be just a `list<string>`
I am able to build first column (`grid.column=0`) using `Listbox` with `Checkbox` in XAML as:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ListBox x:Name="Listitems"  Grid.Column="0" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyResults}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox  Content="{Binding logdate}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>

                        </Grid>
```

User interface is displayed correctly as:

[image]

For the second column, I thought of using a `ListView`(`grid.colum=1`) and updated the above XAML as:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ListBox x:Name="Listitems"  Grid.Column="0" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyResults}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox  Content="{Binding logdate}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                             </ListBox>
                            <ListView Grid.Column="1" Name="CatNames" FontSize="13" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OFMCategoriesNames}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
                        </ListView>
                        </Grid>
```

But the user interface is messed up. Both columns have their own scrollbars. 
[image]

**How to display the columns in the same `listbox` ?**

*************Update based on the answer provided***************
I updated the XAML as:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                               <ListBox x:Name="Listitems"  SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyResults}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A1"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A2"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding logdate}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                                            <ListView Grid.Column="1" Name="CatNames" FontSize="13" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding MeasureMethod}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
                                            </ListView>
                                        </Grid>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                             </ListBox>

                        </Grid>
```

Even after adding `"sharedsizegroup"`, the columns are not aligned properly..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a Grid view inside the ListView like

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        ....
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

or you can use a grid inside your template

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"/>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"/>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"/>
          </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: The columns in the ListBox Grid can be made to align using `<ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` and `SharedSizeGroup="ColumnA"` etc on the `ColumDefinition`s

Comment: @EdPlunkett : thnks but even after adding the SharedSizegroup, the columns are no aligned..

Comment: @Steve: thanks I updated the question based on your suggestion but columns are not aligned.

Comment: @user7157732 It works for me every single time. Let's see the XAML.

Comment: @user7157732 `<ListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"`. Add `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` to the `ListBox`. You can use SharedSizeGroup all over the place in a XAML file -- there has to be some way to define the scope in which the size is shared. The way you do that is you set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on some containing element. `ListBox` is a good choice for the containing element in this case.